# Kettle HTTP Post with utf-8 encoding corrupts soap request xml

Tags: pentaho, kettle

In my Kettle job, there is a module to send xml soap requests to wsdl web server with HTTP Post step (PDI CE 5.0.1). Things were fine till we received Unicode data for this task.
If I set "Encoding" option in HTTP Post step to utf-8, the soap xml request string itself is getting corrupted (as traced with wireshark, network packet analyzer tool, last 2 to 3 lines of xml were chopped off) resulting in HTTP Status 500 error (com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to internalize message). If this option is disabled, the step executed, but with junk characters (????) for Unicode data.

I had already followed the following thread, but didn't worked for me. 
(1) http://forums.pentaho.com/archive/in.../t-133999.html
(2) http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread...g-problem-utf8

I felt this might be a bug with PDI CE 5.0.1 and tried with PDI CE 5.2.0A, but no difference. Is it a bug or whether am doing any mistake here? Any work around to send HTTP soap request from Kettle with Unicode data (without compromising on performance)?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue using PDI 5.2 (and reproduced in 4.4 as well).

The problem appears to be caused by the fact that the POST step calculates the request body length BEFORE converting to Unicode. It then sets the Content-Length header using this length value, which causes a problem because the actual request body is greater than that length once converted to Unicode.

My workaround was to get the length of the request in a JavaScript step, generate a string of spaces equal to half that length, and finally append that to the request body. You must also set the Content-Length header to the length calculated in the JavaScript step (the length of the string + half the length of the string).

It's ugly, but it works.

Example:

```
var contentLen = requestXml.length + ceil(requestXml.length/2);

var padding =  Array(contentLen).join(" ");

requestXml = requestXml + padding;
```

Edit:

It's worth noting that the JavaScript step also gets the length of the request before the Unicode conversion, hence why I'm appending spaces. I wasn't able to find the length of the request post-conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I know this topic is old, but for the ones who are having the same problem. Use RESTClient (instead of HTTP Post) with HTTP Method set to "POST", and application type "TEXT XML".